# How do I Pass a List of Series to a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I realize Dataframe takes a map of {'series_name':Series(data, index)}.  However, it automatically sorts that map even if the map is an OrderedDict().

Is there a simple way to pass a list of Series(data, index, name=name) such that the order is preserved and the column names are the series.name?  Is there an easy way if all the indices are the same for all the series?

I normally do this by just passing a numpy column_stack of series.values and specifying the column names.  However, this is ugly and in this particular case the data is strings not floats.

Comment: ok so strings actually do work in numpy arrays and I have a solution.  Still it feels like a bit of a hack and I was wondering if there was a clean solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could use `pandas.concat`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import rands

data = [pd.Series([rands(4) for j in range(6)],
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=6),
                  name='col'+str(i)) for i in range(4)]

df = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in data])
print(df)
```

yields

```
            col0  col1  col2  col3
2000-01-01  GqcN  Lwlj  Km7b  XfaA
2000-01-02  lhNC  nlSm  jCYu  XLVb
2000-01-03  sSRz  PFby  C1o5  0BJe
2000-01-04  khZb  Ny9p  crUY  LNmc
2000-01-05  hmLp  4rVp  xF2P  OmD9
2000-01-06  giah  psQb  T5RJ  oLSh
```

Answer (score 14):

```
a = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3])
b = pd.Series(data=[4,5,6])
a.name = 'a'
b.name= 'b'

pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b), columns=[a.name, b.name])
```

or just concat dataframes

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a),pd.DataFrame(b)], axis=1)

In [53]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(zip(a,b), columns=[a.name, b.name])
1000 loops, best of 3: 362 us per loop

In [54]: %timeit pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a),pd.DataFrame(b)], axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 808 us per loop
```

Comment: Will the zip be faster if the index/data is the same length for both?

Answer (score 9):

Build the list of series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

> series = [pd.Series(np.random.rand(3), name=c) for c in list('abcdefg')]
```

**First method** `pd.DataFrame.from_items`:

```
> pd.DataFrame.from_items([(s.name, s) for s in series])
          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
0  0.071094  0.077545  0.299540  0.377555  0.751840  0.879995  0.933399
1  0.538251  0.066780  0.415607  0.796059  0.718893  0.679950  0.502138
2  0.096001  0.680868  0.883778  0.210488  0.642578  0.023881  0.250317
```

**Second method** `pd.concat`:

```
> pd.concat(series, axis=1)
          a         b         c         d         e         f         g
0  0.071094  0.077545  0.299540  0.377555  0.751840  0.879995  0.933399
1  0.538251  0.066780  0.415607  0.796059  0.718893  0.679950  0.502138
2  0.096001  0.680868  0.883778  0.210488  0.642578  0.023881  0.250317
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply passing the list of Series to `DataFrame` then transposing seems to work too.  It will also fill in any indices that are missing from one or the other Series.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import rands
data = [pd.Series([rands(4) for j in range(6)],
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=6),
                  name='col'+str(i)) for i in range(4)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(df)
```

Comment: Problem with the `.T` at the end is that it breaks dtypes

Comment: pd.DataFrame(list_of_series) is perfect

Answer (score 4):

Check out `DataFrame.from_items` too

Comment: How would `DataFrame.from_items` work in this example?

Comment: ``DataFrame.from_items([<Series1>, <Series2>, ...])``

Comment: oops, i meant: ``DataFrame.from_items([('column1', <Series1>), ('column2', <Series2>), ...])``

Comment: from_items deprecation... use from_dict: 
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'column1':mylist})

Answer (score 2):

You can first create an empty DataFrame and then use `append()` to it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
```

then:

```
df = df.append(list_series)
```

I also like to make sure the previous script that created list_series won't mess my dataframe up:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is simpler:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import rands
    
data = [pd.Series([rands(4) for j in range(6)],
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=6),
                  name='col'+str(i)) for i in range(4)]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

which yields

```
     2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05 2000-01-06
col0       oPg5       9Af9       SNfq       vnCb       ArCU       8Bhy
col1       IKmX       xS0c       yqCQ       sVov       92CN       WIyH
col2       1x2s       JBk7       Z5vh       km7k       ed1F       pIDt
col3       m9M3       mxil       1v72       Fkme       YooA       5H5b
```

, or try this one

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(df)
```

to yield

```
            col0  col1  col2  col3
2000-01-01  6zbm  UfrI  isNy  wVv0
2000-01-02  Kgej  0SN4  thDS  7BP2
2000-01-03  mcTx  BGDI  5BJC  mUdg
2000-01-04  iVSP  6Rim  6gg9  fY2A
2000-01-05  HzEU  giJ6  HFD1  dE98
2000-01-06  wYCi  nWmp  jqLz  GwKz
```